# How to group content in view by taxonomy terms?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a content type called blogs and in which I referred a Taxonomy term which have three different terms in it.

Now what I want to achieve is three blocks with two recent posts for each taxonomy term.

Which should look like :

```
||       TERM 1            ||          TERM 2           ||        TERM3        ||

         title1                        title1                     title1
          desc                          desc                       desc

         title2                        title2                     title2
          desc                          desc                       desc
   
         read more...                  read more...              read more...
```

I know we can create using seperate blocks each.

I need this to be created in a **single block in views** if this is possible.

I've tried group by in field settings, but it yields me something like this:

**TERM 1**

> title1
>
> desc

**TERM 2**

> title1
>
> desc
>
> title2
>
> desc
>
> title3
>
> desc

**TERM 3**

> title1
>
> desc

Since I specified 6 nodes to be displayed it displays 6 recent post irrespective of the taxonomy term.

Comment: You must deliver the three-term-block in Views, or just in a single block?

Comment: I need all these to be rendered as a single block in grid view horizontally

Comment: The Term names are fixed? There will be more term maybe?

Comment: Let's say its fixed.. What should I do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to display such view and render it as single block using **attachments**

Instead of creating separate blocks for each this seems to be a good idea. Just Create three different attachments in which you can **override the term filter** to get two recent posts each.

**1. Create a block in views and add required fields in it**

**2. Add a filter criteria for a specific term and add a sort criteria for post date(desc)**

**3. Now add an attachment and just override the term filter for another term and repeat it for the other filters too.**

To achieve the grid view I just applied CSS classes Since I use Bootstrap as my base theme by applying the class: **col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4**

Now you can render three different blocks as "one"....!!!!

Comment: Sounds good. Can you be more verbose by a step by step approach?

Comment: Can you also explain what is the advantage you gain by doing this via CSS rather than using the 3 block approach?

Comment: Even if you create three separate blocks you need to apply some style to make it looks like a grid. and It sound goods if we render it as a single block instead of rendering there different blocks on the same region

Comment: And it is also meaningful to create them as a single block since they serve the same purpose of displaying recent news

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a single View can you your job.

In the case you have fixed Term a non best practise approach will be to create 3 Views and a custom module

Views:

- Create new view without add a page or a block
- Add a filter to taxonomy term = 'Term 1'
- Limit the results to the desired number, remove pager, add read more link.
- Do the same for Term 2 and Term 3

Module:

```
term_display.info

name = 3 Term display
description = Display the articles of 3 terms
core = 7.x
package = My custom modules
version = 7.x-0.1


term_display.module

<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function term_display_block_info() {
  $blocks['term_display'] = array(
    'info' => t('term display'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 *
 * Prepares the contents of the block.
 */
function term_display_block_view($delta = '') {
  // Initialize a block array.
  $block = array();
  // In case that we have more that one blocks the $delta will define witch one
  // to render.
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'term_display':

      // Give a block title.
      $block['subject'] = t('Term Display');

      // Tells the theme to render the content using ul list.
      $block['content'] = theme('item_list', array(
        'items' => term_display_create_items(),
        'type' => 'ul',
      ));
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

/**
 * Create the items that will be render in the block.
 *
 * @return array
 *   Return an array of the block's items.
 */
function term_display_create_items() {
  // Initialize the items that will be rendered.
  $items[] = array(
    'data' =>  'Term 1' . views_embed_view('trem_view_1', 'default'),
  );
  $items[] = array(
    'data' =>  'Term 2' . views_embed_view('trem_view_2', 'default'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

All the job is done in `term_display_create_items()` that embeds the View `views_embed_view('VIEWS_MACHINE_NAME', 'DISPLAY_ID');`

A better approach will be to give the Term as a parameter to the `views_embed_view()` and fetch it from the View. So you will have a single View that uses Contextual Filters to give you your results. But follow the above steps and you will find your way ;)

A third and more dynamically solution is using the [Views Field Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) but it will add a huge overhead to your site + will take more time to build it.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your quick response.. But check my answer and verify it whether its a right way of doing this..